# SQL Server: Charindex versus standard where clause statement, what is more efficient?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, database-performance

I have about 9 table-valued functions that are utilized in over 30 SSRS reports that I am trying to make more efficient.

One main statement the functions have in common is that there are many case statements with charindexes searching for a program name from a specific table to determine a value (i.e. when charindex('XXX', product) > 0 then '1').

My idea to make this more efficient was to throw in a programhub case statement within another function and utilize it instead of the source table for easier maintenance when new products roll out (i.e. new product codes launch, they go into a programhub bucket). This would also eliminate the charindexes by adding the new function (i.e. when programhub = 'XXX' then '1').

When I started to test this, I did not notice any significant speed differences (it actually seemed like the old way was faster, probably due to cache).

I tried to compare the execution plans and statistics but they are similar also, with the majority of the cost from clustered index scans.

Any advice on overall efficiencies? Is there a way around clustered index scans or reducing the load? How can I truly tell which query is better for the system?

Comment: Correct way is to extract code from product column, store it as new column and add index on top of it. Then your query will be like `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE new_indexed_col = 'XXX'` or  `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE new_indexed_col  LIKE 'XXX%'`

Comment: I'm guessing that you have something like `WHERE CHARINDEX(YourColumn,'a')` or something? That won't be a SARGable query; so any indexes you have on the table won't be usable, and thus will have a performance impact.

Comment: It seems kind of strange to have the program name hidden somewhere in another string. Moving it out into a new column (if possible, potentially the string contains a list of programs?) and putting an index on it as mentioned by @LukaszSzozda, or adding it to another index that already is being used might improve performance. The reason your approach is not showing any gains COULD BE because you're also filtering on other fields in the table (or other tables that the optimizer considers easier to start with) and the system only considers the program name requirement in the end.